# Returning HttpStatusCodeResult in method that returns PartialViewResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, error-handling, viewmodel, partial-views

I have an MVC5 application that has a method populates and returns a partial view. Since the method accepts an ID as a parameter, Id like to return an error if it is not supplied.

```
[HttpGet] public PartialViewResult GetMyData(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || id == 0)
        {
            // I'd like to return an invalid code here, but this must be of type "PartialViewResult"
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest); // Does not compile
        }

        var response = MyService.GetMyData(id.Value);
        var viewModel = Mapper.Map<MyData, MyDataViewModel>(response.Value);

        return PartialView("~/Views/Data/_MyData.cshtml", viewModel);
    }
```

What is the proper way to report an error for a method that returns a PartialViewResult as its output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a friendly error partial and do the following:

```
[HttpGet] 
public PartialViewResult GetMyData(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || id == 0)
    {
        // I'd like to return an invalid code here, but this must be of type "PartialViewResult"
        return PartialView("_FriendlyError");
    }

    var response = MyService.GetMyData(id.Value);
    var viewModel = Mapper.Map<MyData, MyDataViewModel>(response.Value);

    return PartialView("~/Views/Data/_MyData.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

This way there is a better user experience rather than just throwing them anything. You can customise that error partial to include some details that they did wrong etc.

Comment: To be honest, I was hoping for return value so my front-end would display a error message that was consistent with everything else in the app. But this would work in a pinch too.

Comment: If you need to display anything specific on the view you can always use `ViewBag`'s to do it. The above is how I would implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use manual `Exception`

```
 if (id == null || id == 0)
 {
    throw new Exception("id must have value");
 }
```

if you work with `ajax`, you can handle error by `error callback function`

```
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/yourUrl',
         success: function (response) {
             // call here when successfully // 200
         },
          error: function (e) {
            // handle error in here 
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot return `HttpStatusCodeResult` as a `PartialViewResult` to set the response status code for you, you can certainly still do the manual labour yourself to achieve the same result.

Using the OP's example:

```
[HttpGet] 
public PartialViewResult GetMyData(int? id)
{
    if (id == null || id == 0)
    {
        // Return an invalid code here
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        // Optionally set the description as well
        HttpContext.Response.StatusDescription = "Bad Request";
        // Return null as it doesn't matter anymore
        return null;
    }

    var response = MyService.GetMyData(id.Value);
    var viewModel = Mapper.Map<MyData, MyDataViewModel>(response.Value);

    return PartialView("~/Views/Data/_MyData.cshtml", viewModel);
}
```

Success, by setting the status code directly on `HttpContext.Response` which is accessible from the base class `Controller`, and what `HttpStatusCodeResult` would've done anyway.

nJoy!